# Не удается получить доступ к сайту. Возможно, временно недоступна или постоянно перемещена по новому адресу

Tags: php, битрикс

Сайт сделан на 1с Bitrix (управление сайтом).
При разлогировании (нажимаю на кнопку выход) появляется ошибка "Веб-страница по адресу... возможно, временно недоступна или постоянно перемещена по новому адресу." Ошибка отображается около 1-2с, после чего происходит редирект на страницу с авторизацией. Данная ошибка возникает только с мобильного браузера google.

Кнопка выхода находится в файле pages/profilePage/profilePage.php. Код который овтечает за кнопку выхода

```
<a href="../../index.php?logout=yes" class="defaultButton-gray d-fl">
    <div class="defaultButton-gray--img">
        <img src="<?= SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH ?>/images/icon/exit.svg" alt="card user">
    </div>
    <span>Выйти из аккаунта</span>
</a>
```

Редирект идет на страницу index.php в которой следующий код

```
if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == "yes") {
    $USER->Logout();
    return LocalRedirect("./auth/");
}

if (!$USER->IsAuthorized()) LocalRedirect("./auth/"); // Если не авторизирован делаем редирект
```

Больше нигде не вызывается данный код.

Файл с авторизацией + есть стандартный компонент от битрикса.

```
<?
define("NEED_AUTH", true);
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/bitrix/header.php");

$userName = CUser::GetFullName();
if (!$userName)
    $userName = CUser::GetLogin();
?>
<script>
    <? if ($userName) : ?>
        BX.localStorage.set("eshop_user_name", "<?= CUtil::JSEscape($userName) ?>", 604800);
    <? else : ?>
        BX.localStorage.remove("eshop_user_name");
    <? endif ?>

    <? if (isset($_REQUEST["backurl"]) && strlen($_REQUEST["backurl"]) > 0 && preg_match('#^/\w#', $_REQUEST["backurl"])) : ?>
        document.location.href = "<?= CUtil::JSEscape($_REQUEST["backurl"]) ?>";
    <? endif ?>
</script>

<?
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Авторизация");

LocalRedirect(SITE_DIR . "mobile-myclub/index.php");
?>
<p>Вы зарегистрированы и успешно авторизовались.</p>

<p><a href="<?= SITE_DIR ?>">Вернуться на главную страницу</a></p>

<? require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/bitrix/footer.php"); ?>
```

В чем может быть причина? Куда копать? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Задача решена**.
Проблема возникала из-за того, что долго обрабатывался запрос браузером и на 1-2с появлялась ошибка.

**Решение**. При нажатии на кнопку сделал абсолютную ссылку с указанием на страницу с авторизацей `<a href="https://site.ru/mobile-myclub/auth/index.php?logout=yes">`

Проверку на разлогирование вынес в header и также указал абсолютную ссылку на страницу с авторизацей.

```
if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == "yes") {
    $USER->Logout();
    header('https://site.ru/mobile-myclub/auth/index.php/');
}
```

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но часть ```https://site.ru``` вроде бы не очень хороша с точки зрения SEO. Лучше без неё.

Answer (score 0):

Фактический адрес перехода вычисляется по относительному не от адреса файла, а от адреса страницы. Поэтому если кнопка выхода выводится, например, на странице `/aaa/index.php`, то адрес `../../index.php` будет преобразован в `/aaa/../../index.php`. Ну и куда он будет показывать?

Comment: Он будет показывать на корень проекта в котором лежит index.php. Редирект осуществляется правильным образом при клике на кнопку я перехожу в индексную страницу на которой осуществляется проверка было ли в get параметре url указано logout=yes, если указано, то отправляем пользователя на страницу авторизации.

Comment: Через пк всё отрабатывает корректно, проблема лишь с браузером google на телефоне. Может быть слишком долго обрабатывается запрос? Ведь после того как появляется ошибка редирект в итоге происходит через 1-2 секунды

Comment: По-видимому, браузер на ПК и браузер google на телефоне по-разному обрабатывают относительный адрес. На ПК браузер видит, что ссылка некорректна и подставляет корень сайта. А на телефоне просто отправляется некорректный адрес, полагая, что сайт сам должен его обработать.

Comment: Спасибо за овтет! Попробовал следующим образом - в кнопку выход вставил `<?= $APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam("logout=yes", array("logout")) ?>`. Следовательно адрес выхода теперь абсолютный + на этой же странице сделал проверку на logout, если true, то делаем редирект. Проблема осталась. Ошибка появляется не каждый раз. Когда выход происходит быстро, то ошибка не появляется. На сколько я понимаю браузер слишком долго обрабатывает этот запрос и выдает ошибку, а после делает редирект

Comment: Попробуйте сделать логирование значения $SERVER в файле 404.php. Возможно, какие-то проблемы с редиректом.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, задача решена!